# What happened to the Windows binaries for Apache Web Server?

Tags: windows, web

Today I wanted to start my own private web server, and I wanted to use Apache.
I heard that there were Windows binaries, but I can't seem to find the binaries.

[image: http://puu.sh/mcAe1/0ecf4f1969.png]

It would be very nice for them to reupload the binaries for Windows!

Answer (score 1):

As stated on apache's httpd download page, you can get binaries from third party vendors.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down

Answer (score 1):

"The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software, only source code. Individual committers may provide binary packages as a convenience, but it is not a release deliverable.

If you cannot compile the Apache HTTP Server yourself, you can obtain a binary package from numerous binary distributions available on the Internet." See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down for list of mirrors with windows binaries